# закрытие и открытие окна tkinter при нажатии на "home"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, клавиатура

программа tkinter должна открываться и закрываться по нажатию на home, пытался сделать все вот так:

```
a = "0"
def co():
    global a
    if a == "0":
        root.geometry("0x0")
        a = "1"
    elif a == "1":
        root.geometry("700x520")
        a = "0"
    
    
 
keyboard.add_hotkey('Home', co)
```

но выдает ошибку: переменная а не найдена, не понимаю почему так

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: Закрытие программы или скрытие окна вам нужно?

Comment: Мне нужно изменение размеров окна на 0х0 а потом обратно по нажатию на Home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import tkinter, keyboard

class Application(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.root = root
        self.hide_window = True
        self.quit = tkinter.Button(self, text="<HOME>=скрыть/показаьть", command=self.show_hide)
        self.quit.pack()
        self.pack()

    def show_hide(self):
        self.root.withdraw() if self.hide_window else self.root.deiconify()
        self.hide_window = not self.hide_window

app = Application(tkinter.Tk())
keyboard.add_hotkey('home', app.show_hide)
app.mainloop()
```

без классов

```
import keyboard
import tkinter as tk

def show_hide():
    global hide_window
    root.withdraw() if hide_window else root.deiconify()
    hide_window = not hide_window

hide_window = True
root = tk.Tk()
keyboard.add_hotkey('home', show_hide)
root.title("<HOME>=скрыть/показаьть")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Данный код невозможно адаптировать под мой, поскольку чтоб создать окно tkinter я использовал `import tkinter as tk` `from tkinter import *` и `from tkinter import ttk`, а окно создавал так:`root = tk.Tk()` и данный код адаптировать под мой невозможно

Comment: добавил без классов, но вообще, если у вас это вызывает сложности, то надо разобраться в этих элементарных вещах, прежде чем двигаться куда-то дальше, классы — это ведь основа

Answer (score 0):

```
root.bind("<Key>", co)
```

где root — Ваше TK-шное окно.

Comment: это не весь код как бы, или мне стоило сюда писать весь код в 900 строк?